# Measurable functions in $(N, P(N))$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given $P(N)$ is the power set of $N$ - set of natural numbers, and $h$ is a counting measure. Prove that every functions $g: N\rightarrow R$ is $h$-measurable.

**My attempt:** First, it's trivial that $(N, P(N))$ is a measurable space. Now, we would show for any sets $\left\{x\in N: g(x)<c\right\}$, $h(\left\{x\in N: g(x)<c\right\})$ is measurable in $P(N)$. But this is trivial due to $h$ being a counting measure, so we're done.

Can someone please help verify if my proof above is correct? In particular, I'm not sure about the difference between a function $g$ is $h$-measurable and $g$ is measurable, both are with respect to $P(N)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable because $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains all possible subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sure! But is my proof above correct? I'm just a bit confused on whether there is a subtle difference between being $u$-measurable and only measurable...

Comment: No. U need to show that the inverse images of $g$ are in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. The usual notation in this case: "$g$ is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$-measurable" or just measurable.

Comment: But the problem asked for $h$-measurable. Do you mean they are equivalent to $P(N)$- measurable?

Comment: I'm aware of the following notation: for a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, $\mu$-measurable function is a function which is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{M}^*$, where  $\mathcal{M}^*$ is the completion of $\mathcal{M}$ w.r.t. $\mu$. However, this is irrelevant in your context.

Comment: where did you get that definition of a $u$-measurable function? Because if that's true, I was just lucky in that case. I never saw that definition stated in measure theory books though:P